# jQuery Animation runs pporly on first event

Tags: jquery

I've been building some tabs with jQuery and they've cone along pretty well except that the animation of the tab container size is inconsistent, on the first run its a little jumpy and the the timing is off.

When clicking on a tab trigger it should, fade out the current tab, .show the new contnet (with opacity set to 0 so I can get the accurate height) - adjust the container height and fade the opacity in on the active tab.

it works but is buggy on the first click of any of the tabs, once you click on a tab a again it runs perfectly - what am I doing wrong ?

Check out the jsfiddle here for the full code and demo.... http://jsfiddle.net/pushplaybang/rjS2B/

my script looks like this :

```
var tabs = {

trig   : $('nav.tab-triggers'),
content: $('section.tabs-content'),
panels : $('section.tabs-content').children(),

// Kick off
init   : function() {
    $.each(tabs.content,function(index, value) {
         $(value).children(':first').addClass('active').show().children().css('opacity', '1');
        $(value).children().not(':first').children('opacity', '0').end().hide();
    });
    tabs.address([tabs.trig]);
    tabs.address([tabs.content]);
    tabs.trig.on('click', 'a', tabs.display);
},

// assign incremental classes hrefs and id's to containers (grouped by class), triggers, and panels
address: function(obj) {
    // for each obj
    $.each(obj, function(index,value) {
         $.each(obj[index], function(index2,value2) {
            $(value2).addClass('tabs-' + index2);
            var kids = $(value2).children();
            $.each(kids, function(index3, value3) {
                var kid = $(value3);
                // if its parent is a nav element
                if ( kid.parent().is('nav') ) {
                // add href
                    kid.attr('href', '#tab-' + index3);
                } else {
                // add matching ids
                    kid.attr('id', 'tab-' + index3);
                }
            });  // end loop through children elements
        }); // end loop through parent elements
    }); // iteration of passed obj
}, // end address method

display: function (e) {
    var clicked = $(this);
    var link    = clicked.attr('href');
    var target  = clicked.parent().next().children(link);
    var active = clicked.parent().next().children('.active');

    clicked.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    active.children().animate({
        opacity : 0
    },180, function() {
        active.removeClass('active').fadeOut(20, function() {
            target.addClass('active').show(0, function() {
                var tabheight = target.outerHeight();
                target.parent().animate({
                    height: tabheight + 40
                },200, function() {
                    target.children().animate({
                        opacity : 1
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
} // end display method

}

tabs.init();
```

its a subtle bug, but its annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your bug :

- in the complete callback of the active tab fadeOut :

  - you directly call `target.addClass('active').show` but its children'opacity is not set to 0, causing their deferred opacity animation from current opacity to 1 not doing anything the first time
  - => **you might insert these chained calls** `target.children().css({opacity: 0}).end().addClass('active').show` where **.children().css({opacity: 0}).end()** just goes to the children and alter their opacity.

What you shouldn't be doing (for performance and clarity) :

- you call show with delay being 0, which is so bad cause it creates an animation where you want the result instantly (was? maybe jQuery 1.9 does a better job now?)
- you retrieve the active tab each time. A simple closure variable could refer the last active tab
- you don't compare the one you show with the active one, so that trying to show the active one relaunch the animation
- you don't stop the current animation, causing multiple clicks queuing animations

You might have a look at a slide toggle implementation here :
http://jsfiddle.net/alexis_tondelier/Gf2dv/
which stop animations, refer active item, tests if it's the same and close it in this case, and also listen to outlicks to close when you click outside (which is not completely your case actually).

Comment: hey thanks for the comprehensive answer, I'd like to understand a few things a bit better though,  changing the target chain call in the way you suggested fixed the animation bug (though I thought setting that up in my init method had set all the childrens opacity to 0?) and I wrapped it all in an if !hasClass active  to avoid re launching  the animation.

Comment: Sorry to see this only now, but of course it is better to apply it in the init call. And there you call the method children with arguments opacity and 0, where using the css method would be a better choice. :-)

Comment: Further  - I used the .show really as a cheap way to get the callback as I wanted to do everything else after essentially setting the tab to be active to block before retrieving its height to adjust the container and then display the content.  I'm not 100% sure regarding closures - the how and why - I've read the explanations and poured over blogs trying to get my head around it, but if you could explain what you mean in this context it would be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: just realized what a stupid mistake I made in the init syntax - I've corrected that as well  - but I'm really interested in the performance tips you talked about

Comment: I've updated the JS fiddle, but any aditional info would be great

Comment: You implemented your tabs component as a static component so you cannot really enclose a variable in a function local scope. You will keep direct access to this pointer from the tabs object interface. You will be able to refer the active tab as a property of the tabs object, the same way you access tabs.trig but let's say it will be tabs.active . If you really want to enclose this pointer, you will have to encapsulate the tabs component creation in a function.

Comment: Then, each time you show a tab, you set this pointer to the shown tab.

Comment: And before setting it to the new tab, you will use it to know the one you have to hide. The performance gain resides in the fact you won't have to traverse the DOM each time you hide a tab. The larger is the amount of tabs, the better is the performance gain. However, in your case, it's quite useless :-)